# M Blossoming Groups of length atleast K

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview recently, I still cannot come up with a solution.

There is a garden with N slots. In each slot, there is a flower. The N flowers will bloom one by one in N days. In each day, there will be exactly one flower blooming and it will be in the status of blooming since then.

Given an array flowers consists of number from 1 to N. Each number in the array represents the place where the flower will open in that day.

For example, flowers[i] = x means that the unique flower that blooms at day i will be at position x, where i and x will be in the range from 1 to N.

Also given an integer K and M, you need to output in which latest day there exists M blossoming groups of length atleast K in the status of blooming.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code (or psuedocode) at all yet?

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, I did wrote the code using Binary Indexed Trees but i am stuck at how to figure out if some flower is inserted in the middle of group then how can I figure out that it is a continous group of atleast K length. if flower is added at end or beginning then it's easy we just need to check the no of ones in i, i+k+1 or i to i-k-1. But what if that flower comes in the middle of sequence and makes that sequence of length k ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Plz give some directions for this. Thanks

Comment: If there are `K+1` flowers in bloom in a row, does that count as 2 groups of length `K`?

Comment: @user3386109 No it's just one group.

Comment: Are you allowed to use O(n) extra space?

Comment: If you've written some code already, you should post it in the question itself so that readers know what you've accomplished already and don't reinvent the wheel - read the How to Ask page.

Comment: @user3386109 yes O(n) extra space and O(nlogn) time

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's just a BITrees code not the actual logic.

Comment: @user3386109 What is the logic ?

Comment: @user3386109 I somehow figured out the logic using BIT but stuck on the case like this 
F?FF___FFFF where if Flower comes in middle I don't know how to check if there is contiguous size of K or not because there are some Flowers left and some right.

Comment: Yes, that was the case that was giving me trouble as well. But I think @Vishal has figured it out: binary search for the correct day on a transformed array.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach

transform array 
flowers[i] = x to flowers2[x]=i

Now can start iterating with day=1..N

flower at position i will be blossom if flowers2[i]<=day. Now all you have to do it count how many consecutive groups you have with size>=K - O(n2) solution.

This can be optimized to O(nlong) by realizing that as day grow from 1 to N ..groups are going to be bigger in size and smaller in number. So do something like binary search. Start with day = N/2. Let's say min group size for this is k and number of groups are m. Now if kM choose day as mid of upper range ( N/2, N ) else mid of lower range ( 0, N/2 ). Do it iteratively until you find ans. This will only work if answer always exists

Comment: This is O(N^2) approach as there are two for loops of N.

Comment: Yes. I just meant finding groups with size >k can be done O(n)

Comment: But before that you are iterating on no of days also right?

Comment: Yes I just meant finding groups of size > k can be done in O(n)

Comment: Yes I understood that but I need the overall complexity O(nlogn) not O(n^2).

Comment: This can be optimized to O(nlong) by realizing that as day grow from 1 to N ..groups are going to be bigger in size and smaller in number. So do something like binary search. Start with day = N/2. Let's say min group size for this is k and number of groups are m. Now if k<K || m>M choose day as mid of upper range ( N/2, N ) else mid of lower range ( 0, N/2 ). Do it iteratively until you find ans. This will only work if answer always exists